# Custom search fields and AJAX support

Tags: filters, search, actions

I am trying to rewrite the search. I used the action `pre_get_posts` and the filters `posts_where` and `posts_join`. The page loads with my custom filters. But I can't make it work with AJAX. How can I make it work? The action and filters are not trigerred, probably.

#### Code of filters

```
function search_filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if(is_main_query() && is_search()) {
        if(get_query_var('a_lyon')) {
            $where .= " AND (sp_pm1.meta_key = 'post_code' AND sp_pm1.meta_value BETWEEN '69000' AND '69009') ";
        }

        if(get_query_var('autour_de_lyon')) {
            $where .= " AND (sp_pm2.meta_key = 'post_code' AND sp_pm2.meta_value BETWEEN '69000' AND '69999' OR sp_pm2.meta_key = 'post_code' AND sp_pm2.meta_value BETWEEN '38200' AND '38299') ";
        }

        if(get_query_var('when') && get_query_var('when') != '') {
            $time = strtotime(get_query_var('when'));
            if($time != -1) {
                $date = date('Y-m-d', $time);
                $where .= " AND ({$wpdb->posts}.post_date BETWEEN '{$date} 00:00:00' AND '{$date} 23:59:59') ";
            }
        }

        if(get_query_var('gratuit')) {
            $where .= " AND (sp_pm3.meta_key = 'price' AND (sp_pm3.meta_value IS NULL OR wp_postmeta.meta_value = 0 OR wp_postmeta.meta_value = '')) ";
        }
    }

    return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'search_filter_where');

function search_posts_join( $join = '' ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if(is_main_query() && is_search()) {
        if(get_query_var('a_lyon')) {
            $join .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta sp_pm1 ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = sp_pm1.post_id) ";
        }

        if(get_query_var('autour_de_lyon')) {
            $join .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta sp_pm2 ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = sp_pm2.post_id) ";
        }

        if(get_query_var('gratuit')) {
            $join .= " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta sp_pm3 ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = sp_pm3.post_id AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key IS NULL OR wp_postmeta.meta_key LIKE 'price')) ";
        }
    }

    return $join;
}
add_filter('posts_join','search_posts_join');

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( WP_Query $query ) {

    if (is_main_query() && $query->is_search()) {
        $meta_query = array('relation' => 'AND');

        if(get_query_var('jeune_public'))
            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key'       => 'jeune_public',
                'value'     => '1',
                'compare'   => '='
            );

        if(get_query_var('gratuit'))
            $meta_query[] = array(
                    'key'       => 'price',
                    'value'     => array('', '0'),
                    'compare'   => 'IN'
            );

        if(get_query_var('location') && get_query_var('location') != '')
            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key'       => 'location',
                'value'     => get_query_var('location'),
                'compare'   => 'LIKE'
            );

        $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
    }

});
```

#### AJAX search code

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_search_posts', 'em_ajax_search_posts' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_search_posts', 'em_ajax_search_posts' );

function em_ajax_search_posts() {
    global $wp_query, $wpdb;

    $page = (int) $_GET['page'];
    $posts_per_page = get_option('posts_per_page');

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'paged' => $page,
        's' => $_GET['s'],
        'when' => $_GET['when'],
        'location' => $_GET['location'],
        'a_lyon' => $_GET['a_lyon'],
    );

    $wp_query = new wp_query( $args );
    echo get_template_part( 'page-templates/nillloop-stylefive' ); die;
}
```

Comment: are you sure `is_main_query` and `is_search` are both true for a query run in an ajax request?

Comment: @milo, Well, I'm not sure. I will check it.

Comment: I have not had s chance to test it but i pretty sure that most of the theme template tags are not going to work with AJAX requests.